# Chat server using socket.io, message not appending to list

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I was trying to implement a chat server in node.js using socket.io, as given on the socket.io website. Everything seems to work fine except that the messages are not getting appended in the list I have made on the client side's HTML code.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**server code**

```
var express = require('express');
var soc = require('socket.io')
var http = require('http');
var ip = require('ip');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
var io = soc(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/chat.html");
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var address = socket.handshake.address;
    var pos = address.indexOf('1');
    var len = address.length;
    address = address.slice(-1 * (len - pos));
    /*if(address[0] === ':') {
        address = ip.address();
    }*/
    console.log(address + ' connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log(address + ' disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        io.emit('update', message);
    });
});
```

**client code**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form id="form" action="" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%;">
        Chat: <input style="width: 90%;" type="text" name="chat">
        <input type="submit" style="margin: 2px 50%">
    </form>
    <ul id="myList"></ul>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var myList = document.getElementById('myList');
    var socket = io();
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
        socket.emit('message', form.chat.value);
    });
    socket.on('update', function(msg) {
        var node = document.createElement('li');
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(msg);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(node);
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you restart your node server while going through the examples? Do you get the data in the update callback?

Comment: Yes, as it is I am using nodemon...Yes, Im getting data in the update callback. @JeremyJackson

Comment: In the update callback, i emitted another event and sent the message to server console, just to check whether im receiving the message, and yes i am receiving it, still append is not happening. @JeremyJackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does add it to the list, but then gets cleared immediately when the page reloads as a result of you submitting a form.

Try calling `preventDefault()` on the event thats passed into the submit handler in chat.html:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('message', form.chat.value);
});
```